# sqlalchemy: Renaming Column Names

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am just beginning to learn sqlalchemy so I apologize for such a basic question.

Is there a way to rename the column names using the Core table definition section rather than having to do it as part of the mapper's properties?

```
        t_Nations = Table(
            'Nations', metadata,
            Column('Code', String(10), primary_key=True, unique=True),
            Column('CommonName', String(50)),
            Column('FullName', String(100))
        )

        mapper(Nation, t_Nations, properties={
            'code': t_Nations.c.Code,
            'common_name': t_Nations.c.CommonName,
            'factor': t_Nations.c.Factor
        })
```

I know you can do it in the ORM process by the following:

```
        class Master_Nations(Base):
            __tablename__ = "Nations"

            code = Column('Code', String(10), primary_key=True)
            common_name = Column('CommonName', String(50))
            factor = Column('Factor', Numeric(5, 1))
```

For example, I wanted to rename the 'CommonName' column coming out of the Nations table to be 'common_name' in order for it line up correctly with my domain model classes.

Thank you very much for the help.
TB

Comment: There is a column parameter named [key](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=column#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.key) but I've never had the occasion to use it.

Comment: I will look into this parameter - thank you for the tip. I will post back if that the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Gord was correct - the 'key' parameter allowed me to rename the column name in the Table definition. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: how does this actually help?

Comment: thanks. appreciate the give back to the community.